# D3 regenerate(reload/reinitiate) collabsible tree

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

I am using D3.js to draw a tree, the tree are based on the json files.
E.G. There two json files: a.json and b.json. When I click a.json, draw the tree for a.json and draw the tree for b.json when clicked.
There are 4 nodes in a.json and 10 nodes in b.json file.
The question is when I click a.json first and then click b.json, the first 4 nodes (nodes of a.json) will remained(does not disappear), and the left 6 nodes of b.json will be showed.
If I click b.json first and click a.json later, the tree will only reduce 6 nodes, the node text will not change to the text of a.json.

```
$("body").on("click",".hash_name",function(){ 
  var hs = $(this).attr('id');
  var repo_path = $("#repo_path").val();
  var file_name = $(this).attr('name');
  $("#file_name").val(file_name);
  var file_path = repo_path+'/'+file_name;
  $.post('../../admini/feature_matrix/git_operation.php',
    {
        hs:hs,
        repo_path:repo_path,
        type:5
    },
    function (output){
        $('#source_feature_content').html(JSON.stringify(output));
        root    = output;
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;

        function collapse(d) {
          if (d.children) {
            d._children = d.children;
            d._children.forEach(collapse);
            d.children = null;
          }
        }

        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
    },"json");
});
var margin = {top: 10, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 80},
width = 1024 - margin.right - margin.left,
height = 900 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
    duration = 300,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([height, width]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; }); // change to vertical

var svg = d3.select("#feature_tree").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");

function update(source) {
  // Recompute the new height
  var levelWidth = [1];
  var childCount = function(level, n) {
    if(n.children && n.children.length > 0) {
      if(levelWidth.length <= level + 1) levelWidth.push(0);

      levelWidth[level+1] += n.children.length;
      n.children.forEach(function(d) {
        childCount(level + 1, d);
      });
    }
  };
  childCount(0, root);  
  var newHeight = d3.max(levelWidth) * 50; // 50 pixels per line  
  tree = tree.size([newHeight, width]);

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
      links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180;});

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });      // change to vertical

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })  // change to vertical
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});  
      })
      .remove();

  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
   update(d);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you already have the code to do what you want. Could you explain how it's not working for you?

Comment: fixed, I added a new function 'and add d3.select("svg").remove()' and moved the margin, i, tree, diagonal, svg and d3.select under the 'Click' event, it is working correctly